# Wrong result of Laplace Transformation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I am trying to calculate the Laplace Transformation of the following function:
$$f(x) = \theta(t+1)-\theta(t-1)$$

where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function defined as:
$${\displaystyle \theta(x):={\begin{cases}1,&x>0\\0,&x\leq 0\end{cases}}}$$

My code to calculate this is:

```
f2[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{1, t < 1 && t > -1}},0]
Plot[f2[x],{x, -2, 2},Evaluated -> True]
lapl[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f2[t], t, s] 
lapl[s]
```

But the output I get from Mathematica is $$\frac{1-cosh(s)+sinh(s)}{s}$$
When running the following transformation integral in wolfram alpha
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\theta(t+1)-\theta(t-1))*e^{-st}dt$$ the result I get is: $\frac{2sinh(s)}{s}$ for $\Re(s)>0$ which seems to be correct.

My question is: Why are the results different?
I am using Wolfram Engine Version 13.1 in Wolfram Cloud Version 1.64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your integral is wrong.  [Laplace transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html)  is defined from $0$ to $\infty$ not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The 2-sided Laplace transform is defined from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ but that is not the Mathematica command uses.

[image]

Mathematica result matches the integral directly:

```
f2[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, t < 1 && t > -1}}, 0]
LaplaceTransform[f2[t], t, s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[f2[t]*Exp[-s*t], {t, 0, Infinity}];
ExpToTrig[%] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I see I was not aware that the bilateral laplace transform was another function, thanks.